# Как правильно оформлять php файлы?

Tags: php, безопасность, site

Вот у меня допустим есть простенький скрипт авторизации:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
{
    echo('Welcome, my dear user!');
}
else
{
    die('hacking attempt');
}
```

Не будет ли чего-либо опасного я если я просто выложу этот файл на сервер?
Не сможет ли какой-либо "хитрый" юзер, не пройдя авторизацию?

Вот еще пример, где пользователь сможет без труда использовать php файлы,
тупо меняя значения в адресной строке

```
if(!empty($_GET['login']) && isset($_GET['login']))
{
    echo('You are! '.$_GET['login']);
}
else
{
    die('hacking attempt');
}
```

Вообще меня смутило то, что я видел на сайте:
https://bezramok-tlt.ru/?mode=2&post=4

```
 //Ключ защиты
 if(!defined('BEZ_KEY'))
 {
     header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
     exit(file_get_contents('./../404.html'));
 }
```

Я не совсем понял что это за ключ защиты и для чего он нужен.
Но он явно защищает php от "лишнего" выполнения, когда это
выполнение не было запрошено на предыдущем шаге.

Слышал также про "единую точку входа". Возможно это она. Если честно - я не совсем понял чём речь...
В моём представлении это некоторый файл, проверяющий есть ли доступ у
юзеров к тому или иному файлу и выдающий доступ ему. (т.е) похоже на
то что было выше...

А сам вопрос такой: Как правильно оформлять и стоит ли делать защиту типа BEZ_KEY (пример написано выше).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.defined.php 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php

Comment: как по мне это уже давно устарело, видел такое в datalife engine (DLE), да и на сайте 2015 год стоит обновление, значит писалось еще ранее.

Comment: Ну, а что модно сейчас?

Comment: модно не использовать `die` в коде, кроме ситуаций когда отлаживаешь код без отладчика и пишешь `print_r($data); die;`

Comment: а еще модно ООП и mvc, шаблонизаторы, и PDO вместо mysql

Comment: нормальный ORM фреймворков, конечно, моднее чем PDO

Comment: уже вижу новые запросы у ашеров - модный мидл пхп. не мидл модного пхп =)

Comment: defined('BEZ_KEY') or die; Так лучше будет

Comment: То, о чём вы спрашиваете - это очень обширная тема, и называется web-безопасность. Это как отдельный предмет - нужно изучать, всё в ответе не напишешь.

Comment: Александр, конечно, но самые главные проблемы безопасности пусть лежат на безопасниках. А я хочу узнать основы основ. Азы. Аля "как создать простой чатик, не создав дыр для sql-инъекций или почему нужно фильтровать данные, получаемые от пользователя"

Comment: Иными словами, я хочу узнать те вещи о безопасности, которые делают абсолютно все. А если кто-то и не сделает и, допустим, выложит "дырявый" код на какой-либо форум, то ему тут же ответят "ээ, Вася, так никто не делает". Ну, думаю, суть понятна ;3

Answer (score -1):

Вообще-то, если надо использовать параметры из GET или POST запросов, входные данные необходимо фильтровать. Для этого есть удобная функция **filter_input** с различными флагами. 
Там есть коменты от пользователей, которые приводят примеры, которые помогут вам улучшить подобный код

```
!empty($_GET['login']) && isset($_GET['login'])
```

Это уже выглядит вчерашним днем